# How can we View the DB2 Procedure and How can we execute the DB2 Procedure and just see the output of the procedure using DB2

Tags: db2, db2-400

How can we View the DB2  Procedure (I mean what logic they have written ) and How can we execute the DB2 Procedure and just see the output of the procedure using DB2

Answer (score 8):

DB2 stores the system related tables under syscat schema. So a query on syscat.routines will give you the Stored Procedure content.

A typical example: if you got a stored procedure by the name `update_employee`, the below query works:

```
select text from syscat.routines where routinename = 'update_employee'
```

Using the db2 describe command, you can see the table schema and can determine which all columns you want to view.

Invoking a stored procedure is already answered in "[How to call a stored procedure in IBM System i Access for Windows GUI Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119047/db2-how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-in-ibm-system-i-access-for-windows-gui-tool)" and you can refer that. 
(`Eg: call myStoredProc(parm1, parm2, ?);` )

I suggest you read the DB2 stored procedure details from IBM website.

Comment: For the AS/400, the SQL would be "select routine_definition from sysroutines where routine_name = 'update_employee';". You could further constrain by schema using "routine_schema = 'myschema'"